# Trying to drop rows based on values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, drop

I am trying to drop rows based on the value 'WITHDRAWN' in my pandas dataframe. It is under a column called 'Judge'. What I was intending was to drop rows with the value 'WITHDRAWN' in the 'Judge' column.

This is the code I have most recently used

```
adversary_df = adversary_df.drop(adversary_df[adversary_df['Judge'] == 'WITHDRAWN'], axis = 0, inplace = True)
```

This is the error I am receiving (those are the 3 columns of my data frame)
`KeyError: "['Client No.', 'Defendant/Municipality', 'Judge'] not found in axis"`

This was another I tried from my understanding of pd.drop() documentation.

```
adversary_df = adversary_df.loc([:,'WITHDRAWN'], axis = 0)
```

This one just produces a weird, non-descript error

`KeyError: 'WITHDRAWN'`

I'm a relative novice in art of programming, so if anyone could lend some insight into the main issue, it would be greatly appreciated. Additionally, if someone knows what the non-descript error means then that would also be helpful!

```
adversary_df = adversary_df.drop(adversary_df[adversary_df['Judge'] == 'WITHDRAWN'], axis = 0, inplace = True)
```

Expected to drop two rows that have the value 'WITHDRAWN' under the 'Judge' column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler approach that would work, using boolean indexing:

```
adversary_df = adversary_df[adversary_df['Judge'] != 'WITHDRAWN']
```

Alternatively, if you still want to use `drop`, then you should be passing the indexes (instead of the df values as you do in your initial code). This way:

```
adversary_df = adversary_df.drop(adversary_df[adversary_df['Judge'] == 'WITHDRAWN'].index)
```

Note that you should also remove the `inplace = True`, since you are returning the result df to `adversary_df` anyway (or set explicitly `inplace = False`)